# Eclipse RCP application with Spring Beans

Tags: eclipse, spring, rcp

How I can configure Eclipse RCP application to use Spring Beans? What I can use in Eclipse RCP to create at application creation time and to retrieve whenever I want during the execution? I want that it looks like in Web development I get an Application Context.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all Spring-Jars into a new plug-in and make your main plugin to depend on this. Both should be eclipse-buddys (http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fbundle_manifest.html).
This works for me